# How do I enable 2-sided printing with a Xerox DocuCentre-II C3000 printer?

Tags: printer, network-printer

On Windows 8 installing the latest PCL (x64 / 64 bit) drivers from Xerox the '2 Sided Print' option only displays '1 Sided Print' despite this printer being capable of doing this.

Comment: Duplex unit is connected, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible issue is the paper type. The C3000 will only duplex on paper up to 128 gsm (bond is 80 gsm). Check what paper type you have selected in the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Devices and Printers', find the printer and right click then choose 'printer properties':

Now go to the 'Options' tab and click the 'Get Information from Printer' button:

This will make your computer go fetch all the capabilities of the Xerox printer and populate them accordingly.

For some reason the default installation of the PCL drivers doesn't do this and your installed printer doesn't think it's capable of performing the double sided print.